# Strapi onChange signature

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I am implementing some minor adjustments to a Strapi CMS, customized by my colleagues.

I need to extend the existing plugins with custom UI [done] and to be able to persist the configuration changes. Found the database config and lifecycle methods. Those functions from my model are never invoked.

I was told that the signature for the `onChange` method, which my component is receiving in props is `onChange({value: newValue})` and it is [excuse my English] the new value for the variable named `value` from the component properties [props].

```
const Category = (props) => {
  const { name, visible, value, onChange } = props;
  ...

  return (
    <div className="container" style={{ margin: '2rem auto', paddingLeft: 0 }}>
      <table className="col-12">
        {allSubCategories &&
          Object.keys(allSubCategories).map((key) => (
            <SubCategoryList
              key={`sblist ${key}`}
              title={key}
              visible={visible}
              data={allSubCategories[key]}
              remainingData={data}
              availableAttributes={value}
              onChange={(value) => {
                console.log('value:', value);
                console.log('before onchange');
                onChange({value});
                console.log('finished onchange');
              }}
            />
          )
        )}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This signature that I am using is not working for me. The call to `onChange()` crashes with an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`.

What is the correct way of using `onChange`?

Comment: where is the variable "name" used ?

Comment: my guess is that `onChange()` causes serenader and my props are undefined. i have basically `const { name, visible, value, onChange } = props;` at the beginning. no clue what is the problem `onChange` is having though.

Comment: Can you please share the full code or share the major parts of code .

Comment: Shared the additional few lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the correct signature

```
onChange({
  target: {
    name,
    value,
  },
});
```

Now, it is working.